# Application Pro version security

Tags: android, version, billing

I have a few free (ad supported) applications on Google Play and I would like to give the option to the users to remove the ads. I can think of the following 3 ways to do this:

1. Keep the same application and add in-app billing functionality to it so that the user can make a purchase and remove the ads
2. Create a different (PRO version) application (the same but without the ads, maybe using a flag) and sell it on Google Play
3. Create a different (PRO version) application that does not contain any code but will be used by the free application to determine if it should display the ads or not. That is, the free application checks for the existence of the 'PRO' apk. If it exists, it does not display the ads otherwise it does.

For me, the best way would be the 3rd one, since it will require no extra coding (for the PRO version) and no updates. Furthermore, users will find the application in the applications for sale (the application will have two entries in Google Play, one as a free version and another as a pay/pro version).

What I do not know is how easy it is for someone to 'hack' this method by creating an application with the same package name (as the PRO version) and install it on the device? Can I check for the validity of an APK (in addition to checking for its existence) (maybe by checking if it was signed by a specific key)?

Comment: i like the first option, its give me free trial on my phone. if i like it i just press buy button without installing other app. and easier to manage if you want to update your app